# slicing each raw of a tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a tensor of size (1124823 x 13). I want to go from the center of each raw of the tensor take five elements from the left and five from the right. I do such this simple code. It gives me

**TypeError: iteration over a 0-d tensor**

```
i = 0
j = 6
base = feat.size(0)//2
for i in feat[i, j]:
    x = feat[base - 5: base:+5]
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
x = torch.rand(100,13) 
center = x.size(1) // 2                                                 
x1 = x[:, center:center+5] # torch.Size([100, 5]) (right)
x2 = x[:, center-5:center] # torch.Size([100, 5]) (left)
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: No, Andre. Assume the 13 is my MFCC features  and each feature has 100 sample as you assumed I want to take 10 features only. Starting from the center I want to take 5 from right and five from left

Comment: Do you mean `torch.Size([50, 5])` and `torch.Size([50, 5])`?

Comment: No torch.Size([100,5]) and torch.Size([100, 5]) which means from each raw I want to take 10 elements

Answer (score 0):

`feat[i, j]` will extract one single element from your 2D tensor - hence you can't iterate on it as it's a '0-d tensor'.

Comment: Can you give and idea how to slice each raw of this matrix